# How to constrain function to be capped by a maximal value in a variational problem?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

In a variational problem, where one seeks function $y(x)$ that is an extreme of a functional 
$$
J[y]=\int_a^b L(y(x), y'(x), x) \, dx\;,
$$
one can constrain $y(x)$ by condition 
$$
C[y]=\int_a^b G(y(x), y'(x), x) \, dx=g
$$
by the formalism of [Lagrange multipliers](http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/115_fall_06/lagrange_multiplier.pdf). Is there a technique by which one can constrain function $y(x)$ or its derivative $y'(x)$ to have values in interval $[y_{min}, y_{max}]$ or $[y'_{min}, y'_{max}]$?

I am aware of possibility to define $G(y(x), y'(x), x) = 1$ for $y(x)$ or $y'(x)$ outside the interval and $G(y(x), y'(x), x) = 0$ inside and then apply Lagrange multipliers, but then the solution of my problem seems difficult to perform, so I am looking for other options.

Background: I am trying to find optimal trajectory of rocket with variable specific impulse described [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462710/optimal-trajectory-of-rocket-with-variable-specific-impulse-and-constant-power/463171#463171). Unconstrained solution contains unlimited specific impulse and I would like to cap it by a maximum value. In the problem, the specific impulse corresponds to $y'(x)$.

Comment: Background: I am trying to find optimal trajectory of rocket with variable specific impulse described [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462710/optimal-trajectory-of-rocket-with-variable-specific-impulse-and-constant-power/463171#463171). Unconstrained solution contains unlimited specific impulse and I would like to cap it by a maximum value. In the problem, the specific impulse correspons to $y'(x)$.

Comment: Why not add the background into the body of the post? Comments are ephemeral after all.